# 'ознакомля́йтесь' or 'ознака́мливайтесь'?

Tags: выбор-слова

Is 'ознака́мливайтесь' correct?

I can't find this word in [Zaliznyak's dictionary](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fshare%2Fstarling%2Fmorpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Czaliznia%5Cdict&first=1&off=&text_word=%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA&method_word=beginning&ic_word=on&text_grammar=&method_grammar=substring&ic_grammar=on&text_trans=&method_trans=substring&ic_trans=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=word&ic_any=on) or in [Russian Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C). Instead, I see only 'ознакомля́йтесь'. However, I keep hearing it [all the time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygOMSy01XBM&t=462s):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the known official recommendation (probably, coming from the 1950-s - the argument being: "оформлять", not "офармливать"), the matter is not as simple as it might seem. It's still *arguable* if just one word form is correct:

Документная лингвистика, Н. Муравьева, 2016

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=oikJDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA189&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0Cy60xESFBuDAGJJqRskWcYodctg&w=1280

> *Морфологическим вариантом глагола несовершенного вида **ознакомлять/ся** является форма **ознакамливать/ся** с корневым чередованием о/а. **Ещё не
>   так давно** форма ознакамливать (см., например, словарь Д.Н. Ушакова или
>   малый академический словарь) считалась неправильной. Между тем в **современной речевой практике**
>   она активно употребляется.*

А.Ю.Иванова, Русский язык в деловой документации, "Юрайт", м. 2018

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=x5N2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3OS5f7UZSmgJMT_C0M7tZdxv5FwA&w=1280
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=x5N2DwAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA116&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U39SpnMGk-fPLGGvl-TrXBaQtAK9Q&w=1280

> *В русском языке существуют параллельные глагольные структуры, которые различаются стилистической окраской. Например, глаголам совершенного
>   вида, типа заготовить, ознакомить, узаконить, могут соответствовать
>   глаголы несовершенного вида: заготовлять — заготавливать; **ознакомлять**
>   — **ознакамливать**; узаконять — узаконивать. В этих глаголах формы с
>   суффиксами -ива, -ыва употребительны в **официальной** речи, а формы **без**
>   этого суффикса воспринимаются как **разговорные**.*
>
> *В других парах глаголов типа: обусловливать - обуславливать, сосредоточивать - сосредотачивать формы с "о" употребимы в
>   книжно-письменных стилях, а формы с "а" свойственны разговорной речи.*

From an *older* classic dictionary: Мюллер Владимир Карлович (1880-1941) Полный Русско-анлийский словарь - only the form **ознакамливать** is present.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=cUCFAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1141&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U19Ib4MXSVtDt5gsRkz4V3zaOz-FQ&w=1280

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick search and turns out there is no such [word](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F).

But I think I may have used occasionally this `ознака́мливайтесь` a couple of times myself. It sounds... easier to construct when you're ignorant of the valid form.

Just keep in mind what it may mean and that it is wrong to use it.

Comment: it's true.  https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&from=xx&to=ru&did=&stype=0

Comment: @tum gramota.ru sometimes gives rather strange answers. But this time it corresponds to dic academic.ru. More precisely, this corresponds to the norms fixed in the dictionary in 1940

Comment: @Elena Sorry, I just wanted to clarify your point. (It's not an argument of any sort). I read your comment and couldn't quite figure out **what** was true.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

> **Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста.**

instead of those terrible two.